# What does "Use my on-site activity to show more relevant content" mean in preferences?

Tags: support, questions, preferences

What does the preference setting mean *"Use my on-site activity to show more relevant content"*?

In particular, how does it affect the questions I see if I'm sorting on newest?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The option above it provides *some* explanation:

> We use your on-site activity to show you more relevant content. For example, we might show you questions based on the tags you usually browse, or show you job listings in your current location.

But AFAIK the question filter is only active on the Stack Overflow homepage. The other sites are simply not large enough to warrant such a filter. The setting might influence the job ads you see on other sites in the network.

> In particular, how does it affect the questions I see if I'm sorting on newest?

Not at all, not even on Stack Overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Newest is not filtered based on your activity.